How to overload static method and member method in Python
This is what I am trying to achieve:
class Me:
    def f(self, i: int) -> str:
        return "Member"

    def f(i: int) -> str:
        return "Static"
    
print(Me.f(1))    #print "Static"
print(Me().f(2))  #print "Member"

Is this possible? I tried using singledispatchmethod to add a stub method, but it does not work.
UPDATE: The line I got exception. It seemed it does not pick up the member function version
class Me:
    @singledispatchmethod
    def f(arg):
        raise ValueError()

    @f.register
    def f_impl(self, i: int) -> str:
        return "Member"

    @f.register
    def f_impl(i: int) -> str:
        return "Static"
    
print(Me.f(1))    #OK, print "Static"
print(Me().f(2))  #Me.f_impl() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

